# VB.NET - Get Data to a Datatable from multiple excel sources

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable, vba

I've 2 excel sheets. One has the asset mapping (assets tagged to each employee) & the other has the organization head count (employee ID & the Name of all the valid employees). Now I want to check whether all the assets are tagged to a proper associate (i.e., employees tagged to a asset should be currently working in the organization), if not, I need to get the details of assets that are tagged to invalid users. For this I need to have a join condition from the 2 excel sheets & should load the result to a datatable (which I can latter show in a datagrid view or use to compose a mail to senior leadership).

So, I want to load the datatable from these 2 excel sources, with below similar query,

```
select a.[Asset ID], a.[EmpNo] from [AssetMapping$] as a 
Where a.[EmpNo] Not IN (select b.[EmpID] from [EmployeeDetails$] as b)
```

However I am not able to refer two excel sheets while loading data to a datatable (but I can do so if the data are present in two different sheets within same excel, which is not I am looking for).

Kindly help me in getting the required data from 2 different excel sheets to a single datatable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a way is to manually add rows and content to the datatable using a loop reading from the sources

Comment: @Allan Thanks a lot for your suggestion. However my data is quite huge & I don't want to have any manual work other then referring the 2 excel sheet paths. Also even if we use loop, how can I get the data from 2 different sources..? Is there any other way, where I can accomplish task in Vb.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OledDb providers (MS Jet database engine), try to use [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177907.aspx) statement.

```
select a.[Asset ID], a.[EmpNo]
from [AssetMapping$] as a
Where a.[EmpNo] Not IN (select b.[EmpID] from [EmployeeDetails$] IN 'C:\Data\SecondWorkbook.xls' 'Excel 8.0;' as b)
```

For further information, please see: [How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

I hope it will helps.

See my article on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/702769/How-to-Get-data-from-mulitple-Workbooks-using-one

Comment: Thanks for your valuable sugestion. However I did tried & its giving me a syntax error.. Syntax error. in query expression 'a.[EmpNo] Not IN (select b.[EmpID] from [EmployeeDetails$] IN 'C:\Data\SecondWorkbook.xls' 'Excel 8.0;' as b)'. Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine Is there anything else I am missing to add?

Comment: A special thanks to you.. Your suggestion has helped me in getting the required result. The earlier syntax error was due to usage of single quotes instead of double quotes,

select [Asset ID], [EmpNo] from [Sheet1$]
Where [EmpNo] Not IN (SELECT [EmpID] FROM [EmployeeDetails$] IN "C:\Data\SecondWorkbook.xls" "EXCEL 8.0;")

The above query is working perfectly fine & its what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm glad you've found solution ;) Could you be so nice to vote-up my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a newbie to this site & I don't have enough reputation to vote-up. Once I get enough reputation I will make sure to vote-up for your valuable solution.

Comment: I'm newbie too... Thank you very much ;)